# ARKit place node where finger press is

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit

I am working on an ios app with ARKit and I am wondering how to create a node exactly where I press my finger on the screen but approximately 0.5m into the screen. I know I will have to take into account the orientation of the device but I am still very confused on where to begin. Any help would be great! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is simple.

Add a your required node as a child node to the camera with position vector (0,0,1).
Now, save the world position of that node you created and immediately remove the child node from the camera.

Add your node again as the child of the rootNode with the saved world position.

```
override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    let boxNode = SCNNode.init()
    let boxGeometry = SCNBox.init(width: 0.1, height: 0.1, length: 0.1, chamferRadius: 0)
    boxGeometry.materials.first?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.red
    boxNode.geometry = boxGeometry
    boxNode.position = SCNVector3.init(0, 0, -0.5)
    self.sceneView.pointOfView?.addChildNode(boxNode)


    let boxPosition = boxNode.worldPosition
    boxNode.removeFromParentNode()
    boxNode.worldPosition = boxPosition
    self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(boxNode)

}
```

Edit:

The solution will need a small modification.
To get the world position, create a planeNode before your camera (you may remove it when not required). And do a hitTestResult on the sceneView to fetch the worldPosition.

```
    let planeGeometry = SCNPlane.init(width: 10, height: 10)
    planeGeometry.materials.first?.transparency = 0
    planeNode.geometry = planeGeometry
    planeNode.position = SCNVector3.init(0, 0, -1)
    planeNode.name = "HitTestPlane"
    self.sceneView.pointOfView?.addChildNode(planeNode)



    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {


    let loc = touches.first?.location(in: self.sceneView)
    let hitTextResult = self.sceneView.hitTest(loc!, options: [:])

    for result in hitTextResult {
        if result.node.name == "HitTestPlane" {

            let hitPosition = SCNVector3.init(result.worldCoordinates.x, result.worldCoordinates.y, result.worldCoordinates.z)
            let boxNode = SCNNode.init()
            let boxGeometry = SCNBox.init(width: 0.1, height: 0.1, length: 0.1, chamferRadius: 0)
            boxGeometry.materials.first?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.red
            boxNode.geometry = boxGeometry

            boxNode.position = hitPosition
            self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(boxNode)

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This doesn't achieve what I am looking for. While it does fix the distance problem, I do not want it to be created at the center of the device, but rather where my finger is on the screen. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To start with some simple solution there is no need for ARKit:

```
var scnV : SCNView!
var scnN = SCNNode()
var depthForZ = 0.50

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch01   = touches.first!
    let t_Point   = touch01.location(in: scnV)
    scnN.position = scnV.unprojectPoint(SCNVector3(x:Float(t_Point.x), y:Float(t_Point.y), z:depthForZ))
}
```

If ARKit is needed you can continue somewhere in your code with:

```
    var trans = matrix_identity_float4x4
    trans.columns.3.x = Float(t_Point.x)
    trans.columns.3.y = Float(t_Point.y)
    trans.columns.3.z = depthForZ
    let transForA = simd_mul(scN.transform, trans)

    let newA = ARAnchor(transform: transForA)
    scnV.session.add(anchor: newA)
```

Or instead update the transform of a SCNNode created by ARSession with the previous transForA structure

I hope that helps you to begin with a basic project

Comment: Your solution works except for the fact that I cannot get the depth to work. I am only using the first section. It creates the node with respect to where I tap my finger but it is created at the position of the device. Any suggestions?

Comment: I do not think that is how you can use the unprojectPoint function. The z value must be a 1 or 0.

Comment: Well, according to the Apple's documentation "The z-coordinate of the point parameter describes the depth at which to unproject the point **relative** to the near and far clipping planes" to that means kind of between 0 and 1.

Comment: No matter what value I enter for Z, it always creates the node exactly at the device node. As well it is not linear according to Apple's documentation so 0.5 entered for Z will not actually be 0.5. I have also done some basic research on this function and while it does convert a cgpoint to a SCNVector3, I believe it needs a plane to place the node on. Empty space will not work which is what I am looking for.