# Place Node in ARKit World at touch location

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit

I want to place a node 10 cm away from the users camera. The node should be placed where the user touched the screen (unprojecting). But unfortunately my code is not working. Do you know what's missing and what can I do?

This is my code:

```
func getDirection(for point: CGPoint, in view: SCNView) -> SCNVector3 {
        let farPoint  = view.unprojectPoint(SCNVector3Make(Float(point.x), Float(point.y), -0.1))
        let nearPoint = view.unprojectPoint(SCNVector3Make(Float(point.x), Float(point.y), 0))

        return SCNVector3Make(farPoint.x - nearPoint.x, farPoint.y - nearPoint.y, farPoint.z - nearPoint.z)
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51041307/1733744

Answer (score 3):

**1. Add a tap gesture recognizer first :**

```
    func addTapGestureToSceneView() {
        let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didReceiveTapGesture(_:)))
        sceneView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
    }

    func didReceiveTapGesture(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let location = sender.location(in: sceneView)
        guard let hitTestResult = sceneView.hitTest(location, types: [.featurePoint, .estimatedHorizontalPlane]).first
            else { return }
        let anchor = ARAnchor(transform: hitTestResult.worldTransform)
        sceneView.session.add(anchor: anchor)
    }
```

**2. Implement ARSCNViewDelegate :**

```
extension ViewController: ARSCNViewDelegate {

    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
        guard !(anchor is ARPlaneAnchor) else { return }
        let sphereNode = generateSphereNode()
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            node.addChildNode(sphereNode)
        }
    }
}

    func generateSphereNode() -> SCNNode {
        let node = SCNNode(geometry: SCNSphere(radius: 0.05))
        node.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.blue
        return node
    }
```

Comment: For your hitTest to work, there must be an object 10 cm away from the camera, for which the hitTest will return an SCNVector3  value, else your hitTest result will return an empty array or the hitResult at the closest plane. The answer in my comment handles this exact problem.